# How can I make a SWT ScrolledComposite not reserve space for the scroll bars if they are not necessary?

Tags: swt

I am creating a SWT dialog and the root container is a ScrolledComposite, as this dialog is pretty large and some of the users have a smaller screen. I have trouble with it when opening the dialog on a big screen, where there is enough space to show the entire dialog because the ScrolledComposite reserves some space for the scroll bars. It does not look good to have extra space on the right and at the bottom of the dialog. Especially because at the bottom I have a status bar.
How can I make that extra space disappear when scroll bars are not needed ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for the `alwaysShowScrollBars` flag in the ScrolledComposite.
`ScrolledComposite.setMinSize();` will also help you but set the min size only when you have filled your composite with controls.

I usually put another composite in my SC and then I can simply do this when I finished adding content to my Composite:

```
scrolledComposite.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

Please tell me whether this helped or not.